# Dynamic document.title with useEffect showing old value when navigating back

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react app with react-router v6. I want its title to show the current amount of unread messages, so I created a simple hook that updates document.title to the value that I want.

```
export default function useDynamicTitle() {
  const { thread } = useContext(ThreadContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    document.title = `(${thread.totalUnreadMessages}) - chatTest`;
    console.log("unread ", thread.totalUnreadMessages);
    console.log("title ", document.title);
  });
}
```

This works fine except when the browser's back button is pressed, it will then show an old value from before a link was pressed.

So, to illustrate:

1. **location**: "home/", **browser-title**:"(3) - chatTest", **log-unread**:"3", **log-title**:"(3) - chatTest"

then a react-router < Link /> was clicked,
there is a function to clear unreads on entering that route

2. **location**: "home/chat/1", **browser-title**:"(0) - chatTest", **log-unread**:"0", **log-title**:"(0) - chatTest"

so far this is correct.
I then navigate back using the browser's back button

3. **location**: "home/", **browser-title**:"(3) - chatTest", **log-unread**:"0", **log-title**:"(0) - chatTest"

I know the useEffect ran, because of the logs. But the logged title and the actual title shown in the browser are different. I suspect this has something to do with how react-router handles browser history. I tried using react-helmet and other libraries to set the title, but it did not change the result. I can also go to other routes and the title will remain outdated all the while the useDynamicTitle hook is still triggering on every re-render. Any help would be appreciated.

Update: This happens in chromium based browsers (edge, chrome), but not in firefox and safari

Comment: you can try using the useLayoutEffect hook instead of useEffect. useLayoutEffect is synchronous and runs before the browser paints the screen, which can be useful for updating things like the document title.

Comment: @AkeelAhmedQureshi using useLayoutEffect, it now shows the document.title from index.html for a split second then updates with the correct value. This might be a solution, I'll keep exploring this. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: UseLayoutEffect still does not exhibit the correct behavior. What's more is that I've discovered that this only happens in chromium based browsers (tested chrome and edge), and works as expected on firefox and safari. I can see the title tag being updated in the dom, but the title shown in the browser's tab does not change with it.

Answer (score -1):

if you want to update title in browser dependent unread messages and you have another action to count down or up unread messages and update title you can use my code:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route, Link, Outlet, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

function useDocumentTitle(title) {
  useEffect(() => {
    document.title = title;
  }, [title]);
}

function Message() {
  const { messageId } = useParams();
  return <div>Message {messageId}</div>;
}

function UnreadMessages() {
  const [unreadMessages, setUnreadMessages] = useState(0);

  useDocumentTitle(`NILL App | Unread Messages: ${unreadMessages}`);

  const markAsRead = () => {
    setUnreadMessages((prevUnread) => prevUnread - 1);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Unread Messages: {unreadMessages}</h2>
      <button onClick={markAsRead}>Mark as Read</button>
    </div>
  );
}

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Link to="messages">Go to Messages</Link>} />
        <Route
          path="messages"
          element={
            <Outlet>
              <Route index element={<UnreadMessages />} />
              <Route path=":messageId" element={<Message />} />
            </Outlet>
          }
        />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

if you need change title in all pages you can use context api in your react project like:

```js
import React, { createContext, useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route, Link, Outlet, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

// Create a context for managing unread messages
const UnreadMessagesContext = createContext();

function useUnreadMessages() {
  return useContext(UnreadMessagesContext);
}

function UnreadMessagesProvider({ children }) {
  const [unreadMessages, setUnreadMessages] = useState(0);

  // Update document title whenever there are unread messages
  useEffect(() => {
    document.title = `My App | Unread Messages: ${unreadMessages}`;
  }, [unreadMessages]);

  const markAsRead = () => {
    setUnreadMessages((prevUnread) => prevUnread - 1);
  };

  const value = { unreadMessages, markAsRead };

  return (
    <UnreadMessagesContext.Provider value={value}>
      {children}
    </UnreadMessagesContext.Provider>
  );
}

function Message() {
  const { messageId } = useParams();
  return <div>Message {messageId}</div>;
}

function UnreadMessages() {
  const { unreadMessages, markAsRead } = useUnreadMessages();

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Unread Messages: {unreadMessages}</h2>
      <button onClick={markAsRead}>Mark as Read</button>
    </div>
  );
}

function HomePage() {
  return <Link to="/messages">Go to Messages</Link>;
}

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <UnreadMessagesProvider>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<HomePage />} />
          <Route
            path="messages"
            element={
              <Outlet>
                <Route index element={<UnreadMessages />} />
                <Route path=":messageId" element={<Message />} />
              </Outlet>
            }
          />
        </Routes>
      </UnreadMessagesProvider>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```